# Serializing anonymous types with json.net seems broken

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, ravendb, anonymous-types

*Latest edits after realizing that the issue seems to be in RavenDb library instead of json.net library*

So far I have always used this piece of code to serialize anonymous types:

```
using Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json;

var anon = new { errors = new string[] { "Login error" } };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anon, Formatting.None, settings);
```

It was with json.net embedded inside RavenDb 2.x.

Recently I started a new project. It uses latest RavenDb 3.x.

Now when I serialize an anonymous type, I get other fields in the result string, for ex:

```
{"<errors>i__Field":["Login error"],"errors":["Login error"]}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the anonymous class that you're trying to serialize look like?

Comment: updated my code sample with an example of data.

Comment: Your settings variable name is `settings`. You're passing a different name (`Settings` with an uppercase `S`) to `SerializeObject`. Is this a typo in your actual code, meaning some other settings get used than the ones you specified, or is this a typo in your question? If it's a typo in your question, then putting your code in a new console application with the exact version of Json.NET that you specified does not demonstrate the behaviour you describe, so in that case, please put in the actual relevant code to show the problem.

Comment: Seems to work OK for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k8znUY

Comment: @NicolasCadilhac For whatever it's worth, I *can* get the output you describe by fiddling with the contract resolver settings. Are you really instantiating it fresh before serialisation? And is `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` the actual Json.NET `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` class, or some custom class that has misleadingly been given the same name as Json.NET's?

Comment: Thank you for trying in a console as a standalone test. I was able to get the same result as you. So by checking it more, I realized that the JsonConverter used was in fact from Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json which is json.net code inside RavenDb library. There is still to know why this issue happens in latest RavenDb code and I guess the best is to ask on their google group.

Comment: @NicolasCadilhac - I might suggest that you [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in case anybody else encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was changed in RavenDb 3.x.
So there are 2 solutions:

- Rely on Json.net library instead
- Or customize the settings like so:

  ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() { DefaultMembersSearchFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance }

(note that DefaultMembersSearchFlags is marked as obsolete)