# NAV 2018 development service returns "<WebEndpoint>i__Field" instead of "WebEndpoint"

Tags: wcf, json.net, visual-studio-code, navision, dynamics-nav

I'm newbite in NAV development.

I'm creating development environment, so I installed nav18 and VSCode, set some environment in VSCode and try to deploy first project. 
VSCode ask NAV18 developer port for WebEndpoint value. NAV should return something like

```
{"WebEndpoint":"http://ws-msok:8080/DynamicsNAV110/"}
```

but returns

```
{"<WebEndpoint>i__Field":"http://ws-msok:8080/DynamicsNAV110/"}
```

so VSCode returns message "Error: Could not open the specified startup page. Please check that the server configuration key PublicWebBaseUrl has been properly set."

(project was succesfuly compiled, package succesfuly published, PublicWebBaseUrl is correctly set, nav web client is working fine)

I have no idea where is the problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Has it something to do with anonymous types in C#?
https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-csharp-3-0-features-4-anonymous-type

Comment: Maybe some miscofiguration of Newtonsoft libraries?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767011/serializing-anonymous-types-with-json-net-seems-broken/33784384
Other installations of NAV2018 works fine. My system is win10 updated from win7. Maybe this is the problem?